# How to prevent the Instagram logo from being hidden when hovered over?

Tags: css, instagram

I am trying to add a social media icon for my site, and the gradient is in CSS3. Currently, the Instagram icon outline hides when it is being hovered over.

This is my current code:

```css
.social-icons li.instagram a {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #F2F2F2 /* This is for the default "gray" background */
    url(http://www.example.com/images/social/instagram.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
.social-icons li.instagram a:hover {
    background-color: #f09433;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #f09433 0%, #e6683c 25%, #dc2743 50%, #cc2366 75%, #bc1888 100%); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #f09433 0%,#e6683c 25%,#dc2743 50%,#cc2366 75%,#bc1888 100%); 
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #f09433 0%,#e6683c 25%,#dc2743 50%,#cc2366 75%,#bc1888 100%); 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f09433', endColorstr='#bc1888',GradientType=1 );
}
```

My Facebook logo works, which is identical except for a solid color `(background: #3b5998;)` instead of a gradient WebKit. The Facebook works as it should, and when hovered the icon becomes blue with the "F" in the middle.

Any tips on how to accomplish that here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my problem was that the gradients are treated as if they were images, so what I did was overlap two 'images' to obtain the outcome that was needed.

So the code finalized was:

```css
.social-icons li.instagram a {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #F2F2F2 url(http://www.myprojectsite.com/images/social/instagram.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
.social-icons li.instagram a:hover {
    background-color: #f09433;
    background-image: url('http://www.myprojectsite.com/images/social/instagram.png'), linear-gradient(45deg, #f09433 0%,#e6683c 25%,#dc2743 50%,#cc2366 75%,#bc1888 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f09433', endColorstr='#bc1888',GradientType=1 );
    background-image: url('http://www.myprojectsite.com/images/social/instagram.png'), -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #f09433 0%, #e6683c 25%, #dc2743 50%, #cc2366 75%, #bc1888 100%); 
    background-image: url('http://www.myprojectsite.com/images/social/instagram.png'), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #f09433 0%,#e6683c 25%,#dc2743 50%,#cc2366 75%,#bc1888 100%);
}
```